# SQLException in setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm a new about Android Studio and I'm trying to develop a simple app with jdbc to connect Oracle database. The connection works fine and I can show a table with values. Now I'm looking for a way to show a value from DB using an input value, but when I push the button, I receive an sqlexception and the app collapses.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private TextView textViewConn;
    private Button buttonView;
    private EditText codUser;
    private TextView typeApi;
    private Statement stmt;
    private Statement stmt1;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;



    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "XXXXXXX";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "XXXXXXX";

    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        textViewConn = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        buttonView = findViewById(R.id.button);
        codUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        typeApi = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        try {

            this.connection = createConnection();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stmt=connection.createStatement();
            textViewConn.setText("Database connected");


            TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
            TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
            TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
            tv0.setText(" Code ");
            tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tbrow0.addView(tv0);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setText(" User ");
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tbrow0.addView(tv1);
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            tv2.setText(" Password ");
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tbrow0.addView(tv2);
           /* TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
            tv3.setText(" Stock Remaining ");
            tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tbrow0.addView(tv3);*/
            stk.addView(tbrow0);
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select FEC_CODICE, FEC_IX_USERNAME, FEC_IX_PASSWORD from FE_CONTROL");
            while(rs.next()) {

                TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
                TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
                t1v.setText(rs.getString(1));
                t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t1v);
                TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
                t2v.setText(rs.getString(2));
                t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t2v);
                TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
                t3v.setText(rs.getString(3));
                t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tbrow.addView(t3v);
                stk.addView(tbrow);

            }
            stmt.close();

           buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     try {

                         //this.connection = createConnection();
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         //stmt=connection.createStatement();

                        String code=codUser.getText().toString();
                        //ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery("select FEC_IX_VERSIONE from FE_CONTROL FEC_CODICE = 'Z'");
                        pstmt= connection.prepareStatement("select FEC_IX_VERSIONE from FE_CONTROL FEC_CODICE = ?");
                        pstmt.setString(1,code);
                        pstmt.execute();
                        ResultSet rs1=pstmt.getResultSet();
                        while(rs1.next()){
                            typeApi.setText(rs1.getString(1));
                        }
                        pstmt.close();

                     } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                        

                        typeApi.setText(throwables.getmessage());
                    }


                }
            });


            //connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
           
            textViewConn.setText(e.getmessage());
        }

    }


    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return createConnection(DEFAULT_DRIVER, DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

I'm using the debugger to check the exception but the debug line doesn't go into tis method `buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`
and I noticed that the app runs without to show the tableview and button, textview, etc, during the debug mode. I can't understand when they run.

Can anyone give some idea?

Comment: Can you please update the exception stacktrace in your question?

Comment: I would like to update an exception stacktrace, but now when I push the button I haven't any exception and the app collapse. After threee times, I receive a message:"NameApp keeps stopping -  App info or close app". Any idea about that?

Comment: That's weird. It should always have the stacktrace. Can you please change debug level from `verbose` to `error` & on right side instead of `show only selected application` select `No filters`. After that try clicking on the button & let the app crash/collapse.  Then try to find your related log from that (it will be in dark blue kind of color). Let me know if you get log by doing this or not.

Comment: When I run the debug, I can't show button and fields. and I can't understand why. So I tryed to do what I wrote, but I can't show the button and I can't click the button